# How to send a string, using java socket as client and delphi indy tcpserver as server

Tags: java, delphi, indy

server OnExecute event like

```
 try

  s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  ok:=true;

 except
  on e:exception do winapi.windows.beep(500,500);
end;
```

the basic problem is to send from client to server

Comment: Hint: your server code should not handle exceptions within the OnExecute method. Indy uses exceptions to detect client disconnect (and other things).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it was only for testing

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding the LF character in the end of string in java code

```
 String str = "Test\n";
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 13428);
        osw =new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
         osw.write( str, 0, str.length());
        osw.flush();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }
```

Comment: By default, `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` supports both CRLF and LF as the line terminator, unless you specify a different value in its optional `ATerminator` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau , from now on i understand the use of ATerminator

Comment: Hint: you can shorten your code using try-with-resources (new in Java 7). Note that there is a memory leak of the OutputStreamWriter.